# setInterval goes to negative

Tags: javascript

I'm buidling this pomodoro app.

https://jsfiddle.net/yvrs1e35/

I got few problems with the timer.

```
startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    minutes.innerHTML = sessionTime.innerHTML - 1
    seconds.innerHTML = 59


    var timer = setInterval(()=>{
        if(Number(minutes.innerHTML) != 0 && Number(seconds.innerHTML) != 0){
            seconds.innerHTML--  
            if(Number(seconds.innerHTML) == 0){
                seconds.innerHTML = 59;
                minutes.innerHTML--
            }   
        }else if (Number(minutes.innerHTML) == 0 && Number(seconds.innerHTML) == 0){
             clearInterval(timer)
        }       
    },1000)






    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        breakTime.innerHTML = 5
        sessionTime.innerHTML = 25
        minutes.innerHTML = "00"
        seconds.innerHTML = "00"
        clearInterval(timer) 
    })

    pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    })

})
```

It works if the timer if there is more than 1 minute left on the interval.
If it goes under 1 minute, even though i have this if in the interval

```
else if (Number(minutes.innerHTML) == 0 && Number(seconds.innerHTML) == 0){
             clearInterval(timer)
        }
```

seconds and minutes go on negative ( after 0:0, timer shows -1:59)

I though that else if statement would stop the interval when both minutes and seconds reach 0, but it doesnt for some reason.

@also if i press startbtn multiple times, the timer starts multiple times, and the seconds go 2x 3x 4x faster, how can I stop the startbtn until the timer reaches 0:0?

Can i get any help?

Comment: FYI, interval is NOT accurate.

Comment: For your additionnal question, each time you press the button, you create a new listener. All of the listener use the same variable. So each of your listener will decrease the time. You should create the listener only when you know none exist (so keep track of them) and avoid the use of DOM as storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is an expensive operation. Storing data inside the DOM like this is an antipattern; extracting it and manipulating it stringifies and de-stringifies numbers for no reason. Store state in your JS script and update the DOM content only when a rendering change is necessary. In other words, consider it write-only.

The interval runs multiple times; you'll need a flag to prevent re-triggers (or `clearInterval` before resetting it). Setting `interval` to `undefined` is a good way to indicate that the clock isn't running.

Lastly, `setInterval` with a cooldown of 1000 is a poor choice for timekeeping. It will drift quite a bit depending on scheduling interruptions and other random factors; the 1000 means "wait *at least* 1000 milliseconds before firing the callback". Instead, use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for accuracy.

I'd work entirely in milliseconds and convert to minutes and seconds only for the formatted output. This follows the principle described in the first paragraph about separating presentation from logic.

Here's a proof of concept to illustrate the above points. Of course, if you're doing the pomodoro for fun, sticking to `setInterval(() => ..., 1000)` does make the code simpler, but I think it's instructive to see it from a couple angles if nothing else.

```js
const padTime = t => (Math.floor(t) + "").padStart(2, 0);
const timeFmt = t => `${padTime(t / 60000)}:${
                        padTime(t / 1000 % 60)}`;

const run = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (interval) {
      display.textContent = timeFmt(end - Date.now());
    }
    
    if (Date.now() >= end) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = undefined;
    }
  }, 100);
};

let interval;
let pause;
const initialMinutes = 2;
const duration = initialMinutes * 60000;
const time = Date.now();
let end = time + duration;
const display = document.querySelector("h1");
display.textContent = timeFmt(end - time);
const [startBtn, pauseBtn, resetBtn] =
  document.querySelectorAll("button");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  clearInterval(interval);

  if (!interval) {
    if (pause) {
      end += Date.now() - pause;
      pause = undefined;
    }
    else {
      end = Date.now() + duration;
    }
  }
  
  run();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = undefined;
  const time = Date.now();
  end = time + duration;
  display.textContent = timeFmt(end - time);
});

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (interval) {
    pause = Date.now();
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = undefined;
  }
});
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<div>
  <button>start</button>
  <button>pause</button>
  <button>reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I''l go through the code and try to understand it :D

Comment: how does the ~~ selector works in jquery? how is it translated in normal javascript?

Comment: The double bitwise `~` amounts to `Math.floor` more or less. `~~(1.2)` gives `1`. It's arguably bad style--writing it out is a lot more explicit. There is no jQuery in this; it's all vanilla JS. The main point of all this is to show an example of using `Date` as a timer, which unfortunately requires a bit more fussing than `setTimeout(() => ..., 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Number(minutes.innerHTML) != 0 && Number(seconds.innerHTML) != 0)
```

Changing the "&&" to "||" should fix one problem (which is that it is stuck at 0:59). If you add another condition to

```
if(Number(seconds.innerHTML) == 0){
```

where the if condition is only true, if seconds == 0 AND minutes > 0, then all problems should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your negative time comes from starting at 0 and because of this:

```
minutes.innerHTML = sessionTime.innerHTML - 1
seconds.innerHTML = 59
```

It changes minutes to negative value and sets seconds to 59. You should add some validation before this and don't start clock.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` doesn't guarantee that your function will execute in the precise interval, just that it wouldn't execute *earlier*. This way, on a slow/loaded computer, the function could be called after the interval is already elapsed.

In other words, you probably wish to check if the timer has already elapsed, not if it's *just* about to do so.

`(Number(minutes.innerHTML) <= 0 && Number(seconds.innerHTML) <= 0)`